# exception on db.SaveChanges().Am i doing correct or not?Provide a solution with the correct code

Tags: entity-framework

I have taken primary key (Userid) as foreign key in 'Book' table.It is one to many relationship i.e a single user is able to upload multiple books. BookID is auto incremented.Whenever user clicks 'Upload Books' button, I need to store the name of the book and its path in database with userid as foreign key from `User` table and `BookID` to be auto increment.

I am having the following exception at `db.SaveChanges()`:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries.  See the inner exception for details.

Inner exception is:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'BooksModule.dbo.Book'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

Below is my code:

Here is my model class: Book.cs

```
public partial class Book
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public string BookPath { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my model class of Users: User.cs

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Books = new HashSet<Book>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

here is a method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FileUpload(string id)
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file,Book bk)
{
        var filepath = "";
        var fname = "";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), fileName);
                filepath = path;
                fname = fileName;
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            bk.BookName = fname;
            bk.BookPath = filepath;
            db.Books.Add(bk);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }      
    }
```

Here is a view:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "UploadBooks", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary();
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Upload a file</legend>
            <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" })
            </div>

            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default2" value="Upload" />

        </fieldset>
    }

</div>
```

Comment: The exception message you posted says `See the inner exception for details`, can you post that too?

Comment: why are you using 'hashset'? Surely 'List<T>' would do...

Comment: Can you please write the correct code?

Comment: Firstly, why aren't you just assigning the Path.GetFileName directly to fName and Path.Combine result to filePath - you aren't doing anything else with the variables. Secondly, if there is a foreign key to the Users table in the database - this is likely the cause of the error, as you are not assigning the user ID anywhere. We will need to see the inner exception in order to help you further though.

Comment: how can I provide you the inner exception? you can give me link of your blog if you have or any email address on where I can send you the project.

Comment: Same way you got the exception you posted, look at the `InnerException` property.

Comment: Following is inner exception:{"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'BooksModule.dbo.Book'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: Yes I need both bookID and Id? what would be the code then?

Comment: Which one do you need to be the primary key?

Comment: For Book table I need 'BookID' as primary key and 'Id' as foreign key from User table.

Comment: I've made an update, should fix your problem.

Comment: So you mean renaming 'Id' in User table?

Comment: Yes, notice I put UserId property in there.

Comment: I made these classes from database first approach of entity framework, then also do I have to add these attributes? I added as you posted by they are giving error.

Comment: In that case, how is the database set up?

Comment: I made database first manually by creating database, adding tables and columns and then setting their relationship in sql server 2012, not in the local db provided by visual studio.Next I used ADO.net data model for making these classes.

Comment: Please provide me the code for view in mvc.I have posted my view above.I am not getting it how to pass the userid as foreign key when user clicks the button? Same exception is arising that was previously coming. reply asap!

Comment: I have a simple form which includes just one button which when clicked by user, then user browse the file and click upload button to save the name of the file and its path in database.

Comment: If you already have a database, you need to post the structure of it.

Comment: Here is my database tables structure:UserId nvarchar(128) not null

Comment: Book table:


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Book] (
    [UserId]   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [BookID]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [BookName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [BookPath] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Book_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BookID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Book_User] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId])
);


User table:


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [UserId]   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)
);

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework will pick `Id` as the primary key, and as yours is a `string` you need to supply it yourself (which you are not doing.)

It's preferable to have an `int` as your primary key so EF can make it an `identity` column in the database.

A few other observations too:

1. The `FileUpload` post action is taking a `Book` object that isn't used other than as a variable in your action, instead just declare a new `Book` object inside the method.
2. The `fileName` and `path` variables are not needed.
3. Do you need both `Id` and `BookId`? I would remove `BookId`.

I would suggest your `Book.cs` looks like this:

```
public partial class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public string BookPath { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And your post action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            filepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(fname);

            Book bk = new Book
            {
                BookName = fname,
                BookPath = filepath
            };

            db.Books.Add(bk);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }      
}
```

**Update**

From the comments you made above, there is an additional change you need to make to the `Book` class. First you need to tell Entity Framework that your `Id` property if the key using the `[Key]` attribute. Secondly for the `Id` column you should do one of these:

1. Remove `Id` (as Entity Framework will create one for you)
2. Rename `Id`  to `UserId` to allow Entity Framework to automatically link it to the `User` property.
3. Add an attribute to the `User` property to tell it the name of the column to use, for example `[ForeignKey("Id")]`

I would suggest either 1 or 2 so it is more obvious what the column is when looking at the database:

```
public partial class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public string BookPath { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```